# Flutter Web Save Image

Tags: flutter, flutter-web

I was working on a flutter web app where I need to save an image created using canvas.I tried FileSaver.js library but it wasn't successful for me.
[Index.html](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cfimZ.png) [main.dart](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vtBzC.png)

Answer (score 1):

I created simple package [image_downloader_web](https://pub.dev/packages/image_downloader_web) that can easily download image from web.

```
final WebImageDownloader _webImageDownloader = WebImageDownloader();
const _url = "https://picsum.photos/200";

Future<void> _downloadImage() async {
  await _webImageDownloader.downloadImageFromWeb(_url);
}
```